# Match file name and copy the new data into the master file

Tags: excel, vba, copy, filenames, matching

I receive about 1000 source files (in CSV) everyday. Each contains 100+ lines of data. Every source file has a corresponding target file (in CSV) which stores the historical data. The source files and the target files have the same filename and in different folder. My job is to copy the source data and paste into the target files by filename.

I want to loop through the followings:

1) Open the source csv
2) Copy everything
3) Open the target csv with the SAME name of the source
4) Paste the data at the end of the target file

I can do the copy and paste in VBA. But I do not know how to match the file and do the copy and paste. It is a tedious work but I don't know how to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run it but this should point you in the right direction.

This does not require excel at all.

**Edit** to give more sensible variable names.

**Edit** Error handling and logging added.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set LogFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\folder\file.txt", 8)
Set SrcFolder = fso.GetFolder("c:\windows")
DestFolder = "c:\Windows\system32"
For Each thing in SrcFolder.files
    If LCase(Right(thing.path, 3)) = "csv" Then
        txt = thing.OpenAsTextStream(1).ReadAll
        Set HistoryFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(DestFolder & "\" & thing.name, 8)
        HistoryFile.Write txt
            If err.number = 0
                LogFile.WriteLine thing.path & " Append worked"
            Else
                LogFile.WriteLine thing.path & " " & err.description
                err.clear
'                wscript.quit 'only in vbs - use exit sub in vba
            End If
    End If
Next
```

It is VBScript but Vbscript is pastable into VBA. Or put it in a text file called something.vbs.

Comment: Thanks Trigger for your generous response. I am only familiar with the excel vba environment. And your sample code seems to be a standlone code that can be run on its own. Exactly what does it do? Matching filename only or copy and paste data as well? Also how can I run the code without excel?

Comment: You can paste this code into a Sub in Excel's VBA editor. Or put it in a text file as is (we don't normally use `Sub/End Sub` in vbs) and call it `something.vbs`. It appends the contents of all CSVs in `c:\windows` to the same named file in `c:\windows\system32`. You'll have to do your own error checking and logging.

Comment: As CSVs are text files we merely open and read one then append it to the other. Also not using Excel to do the work but using the FileSystemObject it should be a lot quicker. Whether the programming is running inside or outside of excel doesn't matter.

Comment: Appreciated your help and explanation. Thanks Trigger.